# log4j configuration change listener

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

My application for some reasons programatically reconfigures log4j (in some circumstances), namely custom appenders are registered. However the changes are lost as soon someone edits the log4j configuration file manually.
**How to make sure our programatic changes to log4j configuration are not lost? Or how to get notified when log4j re-configuration happens?**

The application runs on JBoss and the problem happens when its `$JBOSS/server/default/conf/jboss-log4j.xml` file is edited, but I believe the issue is not specific to JBoss AS at all.

Comment: I saw someone has had the same problem before (http://www.theserverside.net/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=52250), but the solution described there is not a proper one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, I suppose periodically poll the Log4j API asking if your custom appenders are attached (using `Category.isAttached(appender)`), and re-attach if necessary. It's rather clunky, but I don't know of any notification mechanism for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is log4j being configured by calling `configureAndWatch()` explicitly in your code?

If so the simple fix is to not call the "andWatch" method, just regular `configure()`.

Is there a reason why these custom appenders can't be configured in the properties file, rather than specially in code?

Comment: No, it's not. Log4j is being configured externally in the application server. The application only connects to existing log4j ecosystem.